# JavaScript: How to find IP address

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Client IP using just Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript)

Using JavaScript how can I find the IP address of the  any user who clicks on my link (which shows a html page)?

I am working on a clipboard application in Java and I want the IP/computer name of the user who visits my web application link.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/get-client-ip-using-just-javascript

Answer (score 5):

```
http://jsonip.com
```

Usage:

```
http://jsonip.com
```

Or:

```
http://jsonip.com/yourcallbackfunction
```